# Do I need to overwrite Google Analytics Data stored in the DB

Tags: database, mongodb, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I try to store pageviews per 7days to DB.  Application has a schedule task to fetch most access page from Google Analytics every 30 minutes
Store page url (active source) and count to DB.

```
| _id | active_source | page_views |
| 1   | /foo-1        | 20         |
| 2   | /foo-3        | 9          |
| 3   | /foo-2        | 2          |
```

Should I remove previous data before overwrite? 
I fear that while delete database, users can't fetch any info.

---

I'm using MongoDB.

Comment: _best way to store Google Analytics to DB..._ Huh? Is GA not enough?

Comment: This question is imho too broad and not _primarily_ so related.

Comment: @B001 I don't know way to store it into my DB to execute query for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically Google Analytics data does not change after 72 hours.   Assuming that you are using the Google Analytics reporting API v4 you can check the isgolden parameter in the result.   If the data is golden then you know it is done processing and will never change.

So there is no reason to request data you already have stored that is older than 72 hours as the data has completed processing.

In the past i have run a request nightly that would select data for the last five days.  Before inserting i would delete less than 72 hours old.  This would ensure that i always got the final totals after a few days and refreshed the not complete data every day until it was considered final

Example of a nightly run.

1. Delete all data in the database for the last three days
2. Request data from google analytics for last four days
3. Insert data into database.

Run though with dates.

Today is 2018-01-11 so I delete all the data in the database for  2018-01-10, 2018-01-09 and 2018-01-08.   I select all the rows from Google analytics for 2018-01-11, 2018-01-10, 2018-01-09 and 2018-01-08 and insert them.

Tomorrow is  2018-01-12 so tomorrow i will delete all the data in the database for  2018-01-11, 2018-01-10 and 2018-01-09. I select all the rows from Google analytics for  2018-01-12,  2018-01-11, 2018-01-10 and 2018-01-09 and insert them.  Notice how tomorrow I will be leaving 2018-01-08 as this data is now processed and wont ever change.

This way you get partial data for the last three days and only ever update data that may not be completed processing

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood. I image that I have to save newest data to my DB to show to user what topic should be trending on week. As you said, I have to check the isgolden and update it in my DB right?

Comment: Google Analytics data that is older then 72 hours will never change.   If you have it in your database then there will be no reason to update it again.   You should be checking when you download the data if it isgolden is true then never request this data again.

Comment: OMG. I get what you're saying in updated answer. I can count page views based on current DB. Before, I image that it will set range date is 7DaysAgo and fetch data from Google Analytics. Thanks a lot. Have nice day.